# Magento admin import products CSV

Tags: magento

In Magento admin while I import a products CSV file and run profile

1 product qty is 5

2 The updated product csv has qty of 10

3 Then the qty of that product should become 15

By default Magento overwrites and updates to 10

Note: I'm using default Magento import/export no extension for this. How can I achieve this to make the current product qty to add instead of
overwriting.

If have to make core changes which I found the file may be 
\app\code\core\Mage\ImportExport\controllers\Adminhtml\ImportController.php in that `startAction()`

Comment: provide sample csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Use some other update script, e.g.:

http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/mass-update-stock-levels-in-magento-fast/

In the loop check `if ($field == 'qty')` and if that is the case

```
$stockItem->setData($stockItem->getData('qty') + $value;
```

You should then be able to increment your quantities a lot quicker than the way you have tried so far.